# Issue in jquery validator popup message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create some popup that will tell user when he doesn't enter name, lastname, number or email.

HTML :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="label-block" for="cname" data-new-placeholder="What is your name?">Ime</label>
    <input name="firstName" minlength="3" type="text" required class="texbox">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="label-block" for="cemail">Email</label>
    <input name="ctct" type="email" required="required" required class="texbox">
</div>
</div>
<div class=" col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label-block">Prezime</label>
        <input name="lastName" type="text" required class="texbox">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label-block">Telefon</label>
        <input name="number" type="digits" required class="texbox">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#configuration-form").validate({
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "Error!"
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $("#commentForm").validate();
</script>
```

That is my code in html and css... I managed to make my textbox turns red when the email is not ok. how to create that popup text.

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: i add some jquery scripts .. like '<script src="scripts/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>' and some other ... like ' <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#configuration-form").validate({
      messages: {
          name: { required: "Error!" }
      }
  });
});
</script>'

'<script>
$("#commentForm").validate();

</script>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML :-**

Validation for Email.

```
<input type="text" id="email">
<input type="submit" onclick="validateEmail()" >
```

**JavaScript Code :-**

```
function validateEmail() {
    var emailText = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
    if (pattern.test(emailText)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Bad email address: ' + emailText);
        document.getElementById("email").style.backgroundColor = "Red";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/1659/) for Email Validation.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using Twitter Bootstrap, and they have a popover feature or alert message that you can use: [Bootstrap - popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)